# Markercluster in Mapbox

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, markerclusterer

I am following markercluster examples from Mapbox library, but can't solve my problem. If you guys take a look at my working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IkHlIhKZguPZw7YiGCBL?p=preview), you will notice this line of code:

```
L.mapbox.featureLayer(markerLayer).on('ready', function(e) {
```

What I initally thought was I could put markers inside of markercluster featureLayer, but I guess it was a wrong approach. Any solutions? Thanks.

Example following [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markercluster-with-mapbox-data/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapbox example you refer to makes an AJAX call to retrieve the GeoJSON data, hence it needs to attach an on "ready" listener.

In your case your GeoJSON data is defined in your scripts, so the "ready" event will not be triggered (besides, you should use `L.mapbox.featureLayer` with your GeoJSON object directly, not a Feature Layer).

You can simply use the [`eachLayer` method](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.3/l-layergroup/) to iterate through all created markers within the Feature Layer, and add them into your Marker Cluster Group.

```js
var clusterGroup = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

var markerLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(markers).eachLayer(function(layer) {
  clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
});

map.addLayer(clusterGroup);
```

Updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fN6xYcn1Lg532eLe39IS?p=preview

Comment: Hey there, I'm trying to use `L.MarkerClusterGroup()` with the latest mapbox (v3.0.1), which comes with Leaflet v1.0.2, but I'm getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: L.MarkerClusterGroup is not a constructor`. Can you help?

Comment: @Andrew I see that you opened a new question for your issue. That is indeed the correct way to request for help on a possibly different problem.